# EF6 code-first migrations: how to deploy to staging environment the right way?

Tags: entity-framework, deployment, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have been following a number of tutorials regarding code-first migrations and am now at the stage where I am ready to deploy to our staging server.

We normally publish web apps to the filesystem and then manually update sites through Remote Desktop (not the greatest I know).

All the tutorials and best practises as far as code first and deployment go seem to be either out of date of specific to Azure deployment.

What is the current best practise for deploying a web app that has been developed with code first migrations (EF6) to a live environment? How then are updates to the live environment handled?

I understand that I can generate scripts using `Update-Database` but then these do not include any Seed Data. Are scripts the way to go?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use DBMigrator update menhod - this will run any pending migrations. The Seed method in your Configuration class will run every time your application starts.

You can also use migrate.exe to run database updates.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I would have thought that the Publish checkbox 'Execute Code First Migrations' would have run this. Where would I need to run the Update Method?

Comment: If using that option you do not need to programatically call the Update function. If you want more control over updating a live environment as per you question you could move to programatically or using migrate.exe. I think using publish option should be fine however